# how to iterate over parameter map in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to iterate `request.getParameterMap` on my jsp it return `MapString,String[]>` but it's not printing any thing in my page. below is my code

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${request.getParameterMap()}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="${entry.key}" >
                    <c:forEach var="paramValue" items="${entry.value}">
                        <input type="hidden"  value="${entry.value[paramValue.index]}">
                 </c:forEach>
                 </c:forEach>
```

Please let me know how to do that

Comment: Well, all you're doing inside the loop is adding hidden fields. By definition, hidden feilds are... hidden. Also, have you checked that there are indeed parameters in request? Print something, debug.

Comment: You are already iterating the array in the 2nd loop so don't you just need: `<input type="hidden"  value="${paramValue}">`

Comment: @JBNizet: yes there are parameter I tried to print full map but values are String array so they are printing hashcodes

Comment: @AlanHay:ya It can be like that but it's not printing any values in second loop